# there is a runtime error in this file handling code

Tags: c, runtime-error, file-handling

This is a simple code to store a person's name and number in a file.the problem occurs when i also want to include the person's contact number.the error occurs after the contact number is scanned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
FILE *fp;//file pointer
char *name,*number;
char filename[]="testfile.txt";//file to be created
fp=fopen(filename,"w");
if(fp==NULL)
 {
    printf("\nerror\n");
    exit(1);
 }
 fprintf(stdout,"Please enter a name:\t");
 fscanf(stdin,"%s",name);
 fprintf(fp,"%s",name);
 fprintf(stdout,"Enter contact number:\t");
 fscanf(stdin,"%s",number);
 fprintf(fp,"%s",number);
 fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: the pointer "name" points to some (random) space!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not malloc() the memory for name and number!

Comment: that solved the problem.i also tried something else.i removed the 3 lines before fclose(fp).So the file would store only the name and this worked without malloc() the memory for name.there should have been a runtime error while running the code here also!

Comment: not neccessary! it is "undefined behaviour", how the variables are initialised

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory for pointers `name` and `number`

```
name = malloc(sizeof(char) * num_elements);
number = malloc(sizeof(char) * num_elements);
```

Comment: Please consider not recommending scaling by `sizeof (char)`, it's always 1 so it's quite confusing (especially for people less used to C, I imagine).

Comment: @unwind; I added `sizeof(char)` to maintain the syntax for `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract of your code:

```
char *name;
fscanf(stdin,"%s",name);
```

`name` is a pointer to a char (or the first char of a string) but you didn't initialized it's value so it points anywhere.

The second line with `fscanf` read a word and write it in memory at the address pointed by `name`. So, basically, `fscanf` will try to write somewhere it will probably won't be able to write.

There are 2 solutions:

- either you change `char *name` to `char name[MAXNAME]` (where `MAXNAME` is a constant value)
- either you do a `malloc`: `char *name = malloc(MAXNAME)`

The same for `number`.